# DCOM C# ApplicationClass

Tags: c#, .net, labview, dcom

i am trying to control LabView(http://www.ni.com/labview/) via the DCOM Component. I am using c# (Visual Studio) My programm does work on some computers, but there also some which generate an exception on runtime. So the issue seems to be a configuration problem. First of all the displayed error:

```
The COM Classfactory for the component with the CLSID {9A872070-0A06-11D1-90B7-00A024CE2744} could not be called because of the following error: 80080005 (i translated the message, dont wonder!) Sometimes the error code is also 80070002 (Then the system can't find the file)
```

Info: The CLSID 9A872070-0A06-11D1-90B7-00A024CE2744 is the LabVIEW DCOM component and is automatically installed during the Setup of LabVIEW

The source code line for the error is also given:

```
viServer = new ApplicationClass();



[FileNotFoundException: Die COM-Klassenfactory für die Komponente mit CLSID {9A872070-0A06-11D1-90B7-00A024CE2744} konnte aufgrund des folgenden Fehlers nicht abgerufen werden: 80070002 Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden. (Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x80070002).]
   iLabs.LabView.LV2013.LabViewInterface..ctor() in C:\ilabSDK\iLab_440_20141119\iLab_SA\dotNet\LabView\LabViewInterface\LabViewInterface.cs:135

[Exception: ERROR: Creating ApplicationClass LabVIEW 2013: ]
   iLabs.LabView.LV2013.LabViewInterface..ctor() in C:\ilabSDK\iLab_440_20141119\iLab_SA\dotNet\LabView\LabViewInterface\LabViewInterface.cs:143
   iLabs.LabServer.LabView.LabViewTaskFactory.CreateLabTask(LabAppInfo appInfo, Coupon expCoupon, Ticket expTicket) +647
   iLabs.LabServer.LabView.LVPortal.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +821
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +95
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +59
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +678
```

Does someone has an idea on this topic?

all the best from germany

CheVeyo

P.S. Can it be a 32/64 bit issue in the DCOM ?
MMC comexp.msc /32 if i call this, then there is a local path in the properities of the dcom component
MMC comexp.msc /64 if i call this, then there is the local path empty!

Answer (score 0):

Closed, i found the solution by myself...

I searched in the registry for the CLSID and there was the wrong path entered ;)

Answer (score -1):

Obviously the error message does say that it cant find a certain file. Why isnt the filename mentioned in the error code?